# Why am I getting an error when trying to use vertcat?

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I'm getting an error when trying to use `vertcat` to concatenate two matrices. How can I concatenate this matrix

```
text = 

  Columns 1 through 6

    'GL/GG'    'go'    'vc (m/min)'    'fz (mm)'    'Fx (N)'    'Fy (N)'
    '[]'       '[]'    '[]'            '[]'         '[]'        '[]'    

  Columns 7 through 9

    'd (°)'    'MA (%)'    'V (%)'
    '[]'       '[]'        '[]'
```

which is 2-by-9, with another matrix that includes double values and is 96-by-9.

I don't understand why there is a problem with this `vertcat` function.
As far as I can tell, `c = vertcat(text,text)` works fine:

```
 Columns 1 through 6

    'GL/GG'    'go'    'vc (m/min)'    'fz (mm)'    'Fx (N)'    'Fy (N)'
    '[]'       '[]'    '[]'            '[]'         '[]'        '[]'    
    'GL/GG'    'go'    'vc (m/min)'    'fz (mm)'    'Fx (N)'    'Fy (N)'
    '[]'       '[]'    '[]'            '[]'         '[]'        '[]'    

  Columns 7 through 9

    'd (°)'    'MA (%)'    'V (%)'
    '[]'       '[]'        '[]'   
    'd (°)'    'MA (%)'    'V (%)'
    '[]'       '[]'        '[]'
```

What should I do?

Columns 1 through 6

```
        1            0            1            0      0.65318     0.045977
        1          0.2      0.42857            1      0.46243      0.21264
        0            0      0.42857          0.4     0.023121      0.26437
        0          0.2      0.14286          0.4      0.10405      0.41954
        0          0.2            1          0.4      0.14451       0.4023
        0          0.6            0            1     0.034682       0.2931
        0            1      0.42857          0.4      0.21387      0.48276
        1          0.2            1            0      0.53179     0.086207
        1          0.6            1            0      0.46243     0.011494
        1          0.6      0.14286            1      0.62428      0.52299
        1            1      0.42857            0            1      0.21839
        0          0.2      0.42857            1     0.028902      0.52874
        0          0.6            0            0      0.16185      0.16667
        0          0.6      0.14286            0     0.098266      0.13218
        0          0.6            1            0      0.19653      0.14368
        0          0.6            1          0.4      0.10983      0.40805
        0            1            0            0      0.25434      0.25862
        0            1            1            1     0.046243      0.47701
        1            0      0.14286          0.4       0.7052       0.3046
        1          0.2            1            1      0.66474      0.32184
        1          0.6            1          0.4      0.54913     0.057471
        1          0.6            1            1      0.89017      0.24713
        1            1      0.14286            0      0.74566      0.15517
        1            1      0.14286          0.4      0.42197     0.091954
        1            1            1            1      0.61272      0.14943
        0            0            1            1     0.069364       0.7931
        0            1      0.14286            0      0.33526      0.37931
        0            1      0.14286            1     0.034682      0.55172
        1            0      0.42857            0      0.56069      0.17816
        1          0.6            0            1      0.57803      0.46552
        1            1            1            0      0.87861     0.057471
        1            0            0          0.4      0.45087      0.18966
        1          0.2            0            0       0.3526     0.028736
        1          0.2            0          0.4      0.50867      0.29885
        1          0.2            1          0.4       0.7341      0.32184
        1          0.2            0            1      0.56647       0.2931
        1          0.6      0.14286            0      0.43931     0.086207
        1          0.6      0.42857          0.4      0.39306      0.21839
        1            1      0.42857          0.4      0.50289       0.1092
        0            0      0.42857            0      0.21965      0.32184
        0            0      0.14286          0.4      0.17919      0.74138
        0            0            1          0.4     0.098266      0.47126
        0          0.2            1            0      0.33526      0.36782
        0          0.2      0.14286            1     0.023121      0.47701
        0          0.6      0.14286          0.4      0.16185      0.54598
        0            1      0.14286          0.4     0.023121      0.20115
        1          0.2      0.14286            0      0.43931     0.068966
        1          0.2      0.14286          0.4      0.52023      0.25862
        1          0.6      0.42857            0      0.43353     0.034483
        1          0.6            0          0.4      0.48555      0.26437
        1            1            0          0.4      0.42197      0.16092
        1            1            0            1      0.80925       0.6092
        0            0            0            0      0.23121      0.37931
        0            0            1            0      0.30636       0.1954
        0          0.2      0.42857            0      0.18497      0.15517
        0          0.6      0.42857            1            0      0.53448
        1            0            1          0.4      0.54913      0.13218
        1          0.6      0.14286          0.4      0.45087      0.27586
        1          0.6      0.42857            1      0.52601      0.40805
        1            1      0.42857            1      0.83237      0.55747
        0            0            0            1     0.017341      0.50575
        0            0      0.42857            1     0.080925            1
        0          0.2            0            0      0.11561      0.15517
        0          0.6      0.42857          0.4     0.052023      0.36782
        0          0.6            1            1      0.10983      0.41954
        0            1            1            0      0.40462      0.27586
        0            1      0.42857            1      0.14451      0.74713
        1            0            0            0      0.65318       0.1954
        1            0      0.42857          0.4      0.55491      0.24138
        1            0      0.14286            1      0.99422      0.61494
        1          0.6            0            0       0.3526            0
        0            0            0          0.4     0.092486      0.26437
        0          0.2            0            1     0.023121      0.38506
        0          0.6      0.14286            1     0.017341      0.58046
        0            1      0.42857            0      0.49711      0.41954
        0            1            0            1      0.15029      0.72414
        1            0      0.42857            1      0.78035      0.62069
        1            0            1            1      0.72832      0.44828
        1            1      0.14286            1      0.81503      0.27586
        0            0      0.14286            0      0.21387      0.21839
        0            0      0.14286            1     0.086705       0.7931
        0          0.2      0.14286            0      0.10983       0.1092
        0          0.2            0          0.4     0.086705      0.41954
        0          0.2      0.42857          0.4     0.023121       0.1092
        0          0.6            0          0.4     0.052023      0.31609
        0            1            0          0.4     0.098266      0.17241
        1            0      0.14286            0      0.65896      0.16667
        1            0            0            1      0.90751      0.73563
        1          0.2      0.42857            0       0.4104     0.051724
        1          0.2      0.42857          0.4      0.36994      0.17241
        1          0.2      0.14286            1      0.47977      0.23563
        1            1            0            0       0.6185      0.16667
        1            1            1          0.4      0.39884      0.25287
        0          0.2            1            1     0.052023          0.5
        0          0.6      0.42857            0      0.18497      0.15517
        0            1            1          0.4      0.16763       0.3046
```

Columns 7 through 9

```
 0.061728      0.26761        0.375
  0.32099            0            0
  0.91358      0.74648        0.375
  0.76543      0.35211       0.4375
  0.71605      0.39437      0.33333
  0.82716      0.67606      0.10417
  0.66667      0.49296      0.52083
  0.16049       0.4507      0.58333
  0.12346      0.22535       0.8125
  0.39506      0.87324       0.1875
 0.074074      0.19718      0.58333
  0.85185       0.5493       0.1875
  0.60494      0.57746        0.375
  0.69136      0.29577      0.47917
  0.54321       0.4507      0.52083
  0.75309      0.64789       0.1875
  0.54321      0.47887        0.625
  0.92593      0.15493     0.083333
  0.23457      0.19718      0.47917
  0.25926      0.49296       0.1875
  0.12346      0.77465      0.14583
  0.12346      0.59155      0.22917
  0.11111     0.056338            1
  0.23457      0.25352      0.33333
  0.17284      0.39437      0.66667
  0.82716      0.94366      0.29167
  0.53086      0.26761        0.375
  0.83951      0.59155     0.083333
  0.22222      0.22535      0.66667
  0.39506      0.38028      0.10417
        0      0.42254      0.72917
  0.30864      0.71831      0.22917
  0.23457      0.47887        0.375
  0.34568      0.16901      0.22917
  0.23457      0.16901       0.1875
   0.2963      0.59155      0.10417
  0.22222      0.25352        0.375
  0.38272      0.39437        0.375
  0.19753      0.47887       0.1875
  0.60494      0.64789      0.52083
  0.75309      0.49296      0.47917
  0.77778      0.69014        0.375
  0.51852      0.39437      0.70833
  0.85185      0.84507      0.14583
   0.7284      0.64789      0.29167
  0.82716      0.16901      0.29167
  0.19753      0.39437       0.5625
  0.30864      0.38028      0.33333
  0.17284      0.35211       0.4375
  0.34568      0.12676      0.29167
  0.30864       0.5493      0.22917
  0.34568      0.59155      0.22917
  0.61728      0.52113       0.4375
  0.44444      0.32394        0.375
   0.5679      0.22535        0.375
  0.87654      0.29577        0.375
  0.19753      0.59155     0.083333
  0.37037      0.80282      0.29167
  0.39506      0.15493      0.33333
  0.30864      0.42254      0.14583
  0.90123      0.59155     0.083333
  0.82716      0.94366      0.22917
  0.66667      0.47887      0.39583
  0.81481      0.67606      0.33333
        1      0.57746      0.33333
  0.40741      0.29577      0.29167
  0.77778      0.74648      0.39583
  0.18519      0.39437      0.70833
   0.2716      0.52113      0.29167
   0.2716      0.25352      0.22917
  0.19753      0.39437      0.29167
  0.74074       0.4507      0.52083
  0.83951      0.61972       0.1875
  0.85185      0.91549      0.33333
  0.41975      0.29577        0.625
  0.76543      0.64789      0.22917
  0.35802      0.64789      0.22917
  0.30864      0.52113       0.1875
  0.17284      0.90141      0.10417
   0.5679      0.47887      0.52083
  0.81481      0.84507        0.375
  0.65432      0.49296      0.29167
  0.77778      0.57746      0.22917
  0.93827      0.49296      0.22917
  0.80247      0.29577         0.25
   0.7037      0.57746      0.33333
  0.16049      0.15493      0.58333
  0.34568      0.84507      0.10417
  0.20988      0.61972      0.29167
  0.35802      0.42254        0.375
  0.32099      0.52113     0.083333
  0.18519       0.4507      0.58333
  0.39506      0.47887         0.25
  0.92593            1      0.33333
   0.5679      0.22535      0.39583
  0.66667      0.19718       0.1875
```

Comment: I think that you have mixed up some types and data structures here. (1) You cannot concat `cell` and `matrix` with eachother (2) You cannot have a `matrix` where there are both `double` and `char` elements.

Comment: @meryem, are you sure that `text` is a matrix? In matlab matrices can't hold strings, only cell arrays can hold them. Matrices can only hold chars, which makes the 2D char matrix into a 1D string vector.

Comment: @meryem If you did what divacar suggested you have not done it. You cannot concat `matrix` and `cell` and you cannot have a `matrix` with both `char` and `double` in the same matrix. End of story. You can see this since `vertcat({'a','b';'c';'d'},['a','b';'c','d'])` will give an compilation error and `a = [1,2,'a','b']` will assume that `1` and `2` are `char`s in ascii format.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed Strings does not exist in matlab. You have a `char` or an array/matrix of `char`s. It is definitely possible to have a `char` matrix and in that matrix every `char` occupies 1 element and every element have the size of 2 bytes.

Comment: @patrik, this is what I wrote, a matrix can't hold multiple chars in the same place, only one char. If you need several chars togethers (i.e. a string) it's only possible with a cell array. From the question it seems that the OP addresses `text` as a matrix which makes me wonder.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed Just because you have multiple `char`s in an array does that not automatically make this a string. You simply have an array (or vector/matrix in matlab) of `char`s. I see that you also programs in c++ so you should know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can only concatenate vertical arrays (of type string) if they are the equal size i.e. the rows and columns must be identical. A similar question was answer here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449791/why-do-i-keep-getting-a-vertcat-error-in-matlab. May be this will help you understand what you are up against?

A tip for you would be to pad the difference using white-space " "? This will make sure that you have an equal size array to work with. HOwever, I don't know the parameters of your operation, so using " " as a padding element may affect what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `text` matrix is in fact a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) where as your matrix of doubles is just a regular double matrix. In order to do the concatenation you first need to convert your array of doubles to a cell array where each element is in a separate cell (i.e. a *96*-by-*9* cell array). To do this you use [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html?refresh=true):

```
text = { 'GL/GG', 'go', 'vc (m/min)', 'fz (mm)', 'Fx (N)', 'Fy (N)', 'd (°)', 'MA (%)', 'V (%)';
         '[]',    '[]', '[]',         '[]',      '[]',     '[]',     '[]',    '[]',     '[]'};
num = rand(96,9);

vertcat(text, mat2cell(num, ones(size(num,1),1), ones(1,size(num,2))));
```